Why is inline variable declaration not allowed for template structs in C++?
The wording of the title is a bit iffy but I couldn't come up with a better one. I hope to explain what I am talking about with these examples:
struct S
{ } s;

is a somewhat common pattern in C++. It declares a struct S and an instance s thereof.
Why is
template<typename T>
struct S
{ } s;

not allowed?
I had expected this to declare a template class template<typename T> struct S and a variable template template<typename T> S<T> s. Instead it results in a compilation error.
The conventional way of doing this would of course be
template<typename T>
struct S { };
template<typename T>
S<T> s;

but if the simplified syntax works for normal classes why not also for template classes?
If the proposed syntax were allowed one could also do this
template<typename T>
struct
{ } s;

to declare a variable template of an unnamed template class. AFAIK this pattern can't be emulated with the traditional approach of two independant declarations.
Admittedly, this is a very niche situation but to me it seems inconsistent to allow this syntax for conventional class declarations but not for class template declarations.
Is this an oversight or is there an actual reason for this syntax to be forbidden?

struct S { } s; is got from C. template<typename T> struct S { } s; is C++ with own rules. What is template parameter?

It was probably just something that was "missed" or not asked for.  I personally do not like the struct { } name; form as I like each variable declared on its own line.

Try to instantiate the unnamed case.

GCC says, "error: a class template declaration must not declare anything else." Anyway, it is not clear why you think it could work in principle. What would be the concrete type of s?

You could end up with S<int> s; and S<double> s; which would be trouble.

"I had expected this to declare a  a variable template template S s..." This isn't possible because s appears outside the class where injected class name doesn't work as explained in the answer.

"why" For many of those kind of questions, the answer is: because it was not in standard, nobody propose it or it was rejected.

Remember that template variable is "recent" (C++14). So before that, it is normal that it was forbidden.

@Jarod42 The class template case is explicitly disallowed by temp.pre. Check out my updated answer. Also see CWG2862

A better title might be:  "Why is inline variable declaration not allowed for template structs in C++?"  Furthermore, "What is the restriction on inline variable declaration for template structs in C++?" may be a superior reframing because it becomes objectively answerable.


Why is template<typename T> struct S { } s; not allowed?

Language-lawyer Explanation
This is explicitly disallowed as per temp.pre:

In a template-declaration, explicit specialization, or explicit instantiation, the init-declarator-list in the declaration shall contain at most one declarator. When such a declaration is used to declare a class template, no declarator is permitted.

(emphasis mine)
Also related is CWG2862

Possible Rationale for disallowing `s` to be a variable template
While declaring a variable we need to specify a type but since S is a class template(not a type) and moreover s cannot make use of injected class name outside the class so the type of s cannot be interpreted as S<T>, so this is not allowed.
Note that one rationale for not considering s to be a variable template may be because a class template and a variable template are two different entities. When using the keyword struct or class it seems more intentional that the user wants a class template than a variable template. For example, consider the declaration
template<typename T> struct S
{ 
    struct nested
    {
        int x;
    };
} s;

which looks more like a class template declaration than a variable template declaration imo. So having separate syntaxes for these two different things makes sense. If you want to declare a class template then just use struct or class and if you want to declare a variable template then don't use those two keywords. Mixing and allowing theses two things will be very confusing specially in a language like c++ where there are already too many complications.
Note that this is not a problem with an ordinary non-template class-type because it is a type and we don't need injected class name in that ordinary case and at the time due backward compatibility with c the non-template class case was to be allowed.

I'm pretty sure that if that syntax would be wanted, injected class name would not be a problem.

@Jarod42 There are two separate problems with it in the current standard as explained in the answer. 1) Whenever declaring/defining a variable we need to specify the type but while implementing a class template, it is not a type as it is a  template. 2) Currently, class name injection is only allowed inside the class template. So even if we ignore problem 1, then also we somehow need to find a way to specify the type of s. If we assume the type to be S<T>, then to allow this rules in the standard would have to be changed. You already know this but this is for future readers.

@Jarod42 Also CWG2862 mentioned in the updated answer.

So from your answer and the comments my understanding is that while the standard currently clearly doesn't allow this syntax there isn't a deeper reason for it to be forbidden. It just so happens that no one ever wrote a proposal for this syntax to be legal.

@hanslhansl One deeper reason is that how to decide the type of s.Should it be S<int> or S<double>.Also there is another problem allowing this which is that s is a global variable so if the type of s is allowed to be say S<T> then the first time the class template is instantiated like say S<int>, we will get a variable named s with type S<int> but suppose now S<double> is instantiated in some other translation unit,then again a variable named s will have to be created but this time with type S<double> in the global scope.But since there is already a s of type S<int>

@hanslhansl continued... But since there is already a s of type S<int> we can't have another global variable with same name s of different type.

I can't agree with your last two comments. As OP has clearly stated in the question, s is a variable template (note the template <typename T> S<T> s in the "conventional way"), not a variable. Because of this, the logic in your answer also doesn't hold. We need a type, not a template to declare a variable, as you stated in the answer and this is correct, but here we are declaring a variable template so I see no problem. It is trivial to resolve the issue in your last two comments: we have s<int> and s<double>.

@WeijunZhou Did you miss the temp.pre part of my answer which mentions exactly how the current standard disallows this. Also, this is CWG2862 mentioned in my answer whose suggested resolution is "When such a declaration is used to declare a class template, no declarator is permitted, because the declarator would be considered to declare a variable or function template in addition to the class template. ..." The declarator is not for variable template but normal variable.

What I mean is that you have correctly explained why it is not currently possible (because the standard says so), but not why it cannot be made possible, and I don't think arguing s can either be int or double is what OP is interested in. The CWG is also just saying that previous standard has some ambiguity and chose a way to resolve it, without explaining why the choice is made (maybe except for conforming to behaviors of existing implementations). Can you actually show what would be problematic if template <typename T> S{} s; is allowed and has the expected meaning of OP?

@WeijunZhou So you're asking why template<typename T> struct S { } s; can't be considered as variable template?If yes, then one problem that I can think of is that this declaration doesn't make sense because it involves two different kinds of entities. For example,a variable template and a class template are two separate/different things.The use of the keyword struct conveys the intention that we want to create a class template  so taking it as variable template would be confusing for some.This was not the case for non-template class as it was a result of backward compatibility with C

So you mean 1.struct S{} s; would not have been allowed if it were not for the backward compatibility, because it's confusing, 2. There is not a concrete example where considering template<typename T> struct S { } s; as a variable template would actually be problematic for the compilation process, but the confusion to human eyes is reason enough to forbid its use? If that's the case, it's reasonable, but you may consider making them part of the answer because I think that is what OP is likely really interested in.

@WeijunZhou Yes exactly. For example, say we have a nested class inside something like template<typename T>struct S { struct nested{int x;}; } s; then looks more like a class template than a variable template to me. Ofcourse, standard could just impose it to be considered as a variable template but imo it looks more like a class template declarations than a variable template. The main reason I think this should be rejected is because it is better to keep separate syntaxes(like we currently have) for these two things.

@WeijunZhou continued... I mean if user wants to declare a class template then they should use struct or class keyword and if they want to have a variable template then they should not use those two keywords. Mixing and allowing theses two things will be very confusing specially in a language like c++ where there are  already too many complications.

Fair. Upvoted even if you are not editing them into the answer as I believe the comments are now clear enough as long as they are not deleted.

@WeijunZhou Updated the answer.
